# Python3: How do I import an excel spreadsheet into python project? (Im using repl.it website for learning python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python3: How do I import an excel spreadsheet into python project? (I'm using repl.it website for learning python3). I want to automate the entering of data into several connected spreadsheets. I'm trying to automate my work so that I don't have to do it manually anymore.

Comment: On an online repl you probably can't. Locally there are existing third party Python libraries for reading excel files, I'd recommend looking them up and reading their docs.

Comment: Why is it that you'd like to access an excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can process Excel files directly if you use a local install of Python and a library like [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or others.

However, as a workaround, in Excel save the file as a `.csv` (comma separated values). Open that `.csv` in a text editor. Copy the contents. In repl.it, click the new file button and create a new file called something like `input.csv` and paste in the contents.

Repl.it does have the `csv` library since that's a native library. Details are at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html. That should let you read in the data fairly easily.

Since you are dealing with several connected spreadsheets, you may have to do this step with each one and create a new `.csv` file as your result which you can then open in Excel and save as an Excel file. However, you really are pushing the bounds of what can be done in an online repl.

If you are dealing with large files or want to skip the "save as csv" step, you'll need a local installation of Python.